# Doctrine/Symfony change character set for a single column

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

In mysql I can do:

```
ALTER TABLE T MODIFY column_name VARCHAR(32) CHARACTER SET ASCII;
```

Is there a way to do it in Doctrine/Symfony? I have tried (besides googling):

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", unique=true, length=32, nullable=false, options={"charset"="ASCII"} )
 */
```

Does not work, although `doctrine:schema:update` generates an `ALTER TABLE` statement, but that statement doesn't contain character set definition.

Why I need this: I have a string(32) column which I want to have indexed and unique. Mysql index for ASCII col will be 32 bytes long, and for utf8 col will be 32*3=96 bytes long. Kind of a waste :)

Answer (score 0):

After discussing this on doctrine irc channel:

https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Platforms/AbstractPlatform.php#L2549

```
public function getColumnCharsetDeclarationSQL($charset)
{
    return '';
}
```

So it seems this feature was planned in Doctrine but never implemented.

There is an open issue:
https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/issues/2326

As for my use case, I decided to use `binary` column type instead of ascii for my index, which Doctrine seems to understand well.